# Create Dynamic MVC Controllers, Actions for Dynamic Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hi I have what seems to be a comlex issue to get around but I'm sure it can be done. I have the requirement to create a dynamically content managed MVC4 application in C#. I understand how to go about creating my controllers and mapping them to views but what I can't figure out is how to do this dynamically. The scenario is below:

A user goes into the CMS and creates a virtual type page in a new folder within the website root. This folder and page do not exist in my MVC application. The URL to access the new page would be something like website.com/newfolder/newpage. I have a fullwidth page view that the user selects as the view to load with the new page.

So my question is how do I create an MVC controller and action that can take the url above and deliver me the correct view and keep the url structure dynamically. I have read a few things but they don't really seem to be what I'm trying to do.

Any help would be great.

Cheers

**Update 29/09/2015**
For those commenting below to ask how this was done in the end the code is below for my route config and my dynamic controller.

Route Config

```
    public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name:"Gallery",
            url: System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["gallerycontroller"] + "{id}", 
            defaults: new { controller = "Component", action = "Gallery", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ContactForm",
            url: System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["contactcontroller"] + "{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "ContactUs", action = "ContactForm", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Dynamic", url: "{*page}", defaults: new { controller = "Master", action = "Load", page = UrlParameter.Optional}
            );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

My Dynamic Page controller

```
    public class MasterController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Load(string page)
    {
        if (page == null)
        {
            //load default page
            ContentDelivery _cd = new ContentDelivery(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ContentDelivery"]);
            ContentPage _cp = _cd.GetPage(1);
            if (_cp != null)
            {
                string _view = "PageViews/" + _cp.PageView;
                return View(_view, _cp);
            }
            else
            {
                return View("PageViews/404Page");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ContentDelivery _cd = new ContentDelivery(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ContentDelivery"]);
            ContentPage _cp = _cd.GetPage(page);
            if (_cp != null)
            {
                string _view = "PageViews/" + _cp.PageView;
                return View(_view, _cp);
            }else{
                return View("PageViews/404Page");
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Obviously there is more code going on in my service layers and in my database for the dynamic content but I can share this as well if it is of help for anyone.

Thanks

Comment: I think you can solve this problem with Routing, since it's not really a new page, it's a customization of an existing template if I'm not wrong?

Comment: That's correct. I tried the routing but I just can't get it to work. This is the routing in my config. routes.MapRoute(
                null, "{controller}/{*page}", defaults: new { controller = "Dynamic", action = "Load", page = "" }
            );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is only one method that is called for every dynamic page, and if your dynamic page is actually a customizable view, you can use routing to achieve this. Just change your actual mapping to have something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute( null, "{folder}/{page}", defaults: new { controller = "Dynamic", action = "Load", folder = "", page = "" } );
```

you'll also need to add a constraint on your route that will check if the folder and page exists in your database (I imagine you store that information in a databse)

take a look at this post for custom routing:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs

also your controller method should have the `folder` and `page` parameters.

Comment: You are correct the information comes from the database. Thank you so much your advise did the trick and the tutorial was really helpfull thank you.

Comment: hi @mackie1908, i have same problem like you.

Comment: I have a question, Can i to  create a controller or not? if yes what's the name of it? can you explain it with more detail? thanks